# need to use `memoize` in custom module in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module, memoization, rails-models

I have a `module` in `lib` folder. Where I have created a `InstanceMethods` module.

```
require 'memoist'
extend Memoist
module MyStudentMethods
  def self.included base
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def find_student(user_id)
      self.student.find{|student| student.user_id == user_id }
    end
    memoize :find_student
  end
end
```

I am using this `module` in my `model`.

```
require_dependency 'my_student_methods'

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # previously I was using memoize like below commented out code
  # require 'memoist'
  # extend Memoist
  include MyStudentMethods
end
```

But when I start `rails server` it through an error:

```
/home/Projects/school/lib/my_student_methods.rb:12:in `<module:InstanceMethods>': undefined method `memoize' for MyStudentMethods::InstanceMethods:Module (NoMethodError)
```

**Issue:** How can I `memoize` the module method?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `extend Memoist` into your module. Like this:

```
module InstanceMethods
  extend Memoist
  ...
```

Comment: `module InstanceMethods`
    `extend Memoist`
its working here

Answer (score 0):

```
module InstanceMethods
  extend Memoist
   ...
```